# PDOStatement execute SQLSTATE invalid parameter number

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I started using PDO for its multiple database support in PHP/MySQL but for some reason one query keeps producing an error message:

```
$account_email = 'test@test.com';

$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM account WHERE account_email = :email");
$statement->execute( array(':email' => $account_email ));
```

Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

For interest sake I tried the other means of implementing it and it threw the same error:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM account WHERE account_email = ?");
$statement->execute( array( $account_email ));
```

I've done quite a bit of research and apparently PDO is finicky with formatting. Is there something PDO doesn't like about this query? Spacing?

FYI: I have read most of StackOverflow's other questions. Sometimes people have extra parameters in the array, other times a typo, some have syntax mistakes that don't produce errors but still impact the number of parameters. In this case everything seems perfect.

Comment: It looks fine to me. Is that an exact copy of your script, or did you make changes while copying to SO? There's probably a typo in the actual code.

Comment: It's copy and paste with the exception of changing the e-mail address for security reasons. Another interesting thing is that I have an insert statement (for logging) right above it and it works fine and it follows the exact same format.

I've also echo'd and halted the script right after the $account_email just to make sure all the values are being passed correctly to the script. They're all fine. I just can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Do you have any calls to `bindParam` or `bindValue` in the script?

Comment: If you follow the advice [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and reduce your code to the minimum you can isolate your problem and may even solve it.As an old programmer I develop code incrementally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to pass in an array, especially for only one parameter, try this:

```
$account_email = 'test@test.com';

$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM account WHERE account_email = :email");
$statement->bindParam(':email', $account_email);
$statement->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer meda -- I'm using a wrapper class though and I don't want to make an exception. I still haven't figured out a workaround.

Comment: By the way, your solution is the one I'm using in this one case so I'll mark this as the acceptable answer. Would still love to know why this doesn't work -- my best guess is a bug. I've eliminated virtually every other option.